# Django Admin отображение

Tags: django

Подскажите пожалуйста есть две модели:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Имя')
    fatherName = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Отчество')

class Contact(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phoneWork = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Рабочий телефон')
    phoneMobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Мобильный телефон')
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Адрес проживания')
    house = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Номер квартиры')
    liter = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name='Литер', blank=True)
```

есть связь OneToOne как сделать что бы на панеле админи отображалось не PersonObject а например фамилия?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

def __str__(self):
    return self.lastName
```